# Populate a Ruby array like [a,a,a,a].. [f,f,f,f]

Tags: arrays, ruby, recursion

I need to populate an array, but not by directly counting and splitting the numbers.

I need to do generate the following:

```
[[a,a,a,a], [a,a,a,b], [a,a,a,c]..... [f,f,f,d], [f,f,f,e], [f,f,f,f]]
```

And I am struggling to understand it. I realize it should use recursive logic,  but I don`t know how to actually build the method.

Comment: You mean `['a','a','a','a']`, etc?

Comment: Another way to think about it is that you're counting from 0 to 6**4 in base 6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
('a'..'f').to_a.repeated_permutation(4).to_a
#=> returns 1296 different combination from ['a','a','a','a'] to ['f','f','f','f']
```

Comment: A lot of good answers, but this answer also taught me a cool built-in feature to do it.

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
(0...6**4).map do |i|
  # Get as base 6 
  s = i.to_s(6).rjust(4,'0')

  # Convert numbers to letters
  s.gsub(/[012345]/,'0' => 'a', '1' => 'b', '2' => 'c', '3' => 'd', '4' => 'e', '5' => 'f')
end
```

Comment: You need to deal with leading zeros. For example, `s = 2.to_s(6) #=> "2"; "2".gsub(...) #=> "c"`.

Answer (score -1):

Yet another approach:

```
('aaaa'..'ffff').map(&:chars)
```

Comment: `('aa'..'bb').map(&:chars)
   #=> [["a", "a"], ["a", "b"], ["a", "c"], ["a", "d"], ["a", "e"], ["a", "f"], ["a", "g"], ["a", "h"], ["a", "i"], ["a", "j"], ["a", "k"], ["a", "l"], ["a", "m"], ["a", "n"], ["a", "o"], ["a", "p"], ["a", "q"], ["a", "r"], ["a", "s"], ["a", "t"], ["a", "u"], ["a", "v"], ["a", "w"], ["a", "x"], ["a", "y"], ["a", "z"], ["b", "a"], ["b", "b"]]`. **Test!**

Comment: @CarySwoveland I guess I didn't notice the requirement about only using letters from A to F... Or maybe there is none?